# Why do two seemingly identical where clauses involving nulls produce different results

Tags: t-sql, where-clause

I'm trying to select all records that don't have a null in a particular column and it's value isn't in another table.

So this particular situation I want to get all 'Instructors' from an import table that aren't already in the Individuals table. Obviously I don't want any blank instructors. My first attempt I tried using in the where clause:

```
(Instructor IS NOT NULL OR Instructor <> '')
```

However the results still included all blank records. When I tried using

```
ISNULL(Instructor, '') <> ''
```

I got the desired result. I can't see how these two where clauses could possibly produce different results. To me it seems like ISNULL converting the value to empty string for comparison should have exactly the same outcome as comparing the column to null then to empty string. What am I missing here? I'm guessing it's to do with the oddness of null values.

Below are the full queries

```
SELECT * FROM [tempimporttblTrainingLog]
LEFT JOIN tblIndividual I ON [Instructor] = I.FirstName + ' ' + I.Surname
WHERE (I.FirstName + ' ' + I.Surname IS NULL) AND (Instructor IS NOT NULL OR Instructor <> '')

SELECT * FROM [tempimporttblTrainingLog]
LEFT JOIN tblIndividual I ON [Instructor] = I.FirstName + ' ' + I.Surname
WHERE (I.FirstName + ' ' + I.Surname IS NULL) AND (ISNULL(Instructor, '') <> '')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ISNULL(Instructor, '') <> ''    (1)
```

is equivalent to

```
(Instructor IS NOT NULL AND Instructor <> '')   (2)
```

not

```
(Instructor IS NOT NULL OR Instructor <> '')   (3)
```

If Instructor IS NULL, (1) and (2) will return FALSE, when (3) returns TRUE.
Same for when Instructor = ''.

Comment: `NOT (Instructor IS NULL OR Instructor = '')` if you really really like to use `OR`...

Answer (score 0):

```
ISNULL(Instructor, '') <> ''
```

won't return blank records, and you have an OR in the 
`(Instructor IS NOT NULL OR Instructor <> '')` 
line, meaning it will return anything which isn't null as well as non blanks, did you mean to put an `AND` instead?